# Slow database loading during splash activity

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using a database in my splash activity. But with every launch my application is taking more time than the previous launch time. Please help me with my query.

```
private CreateDatabase db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                db = new CreateDatabase(Splash.this);
                final SQLiteDatabase w = db.getWritableDatabase();
                w.execSQL("insert into Fin values( '" +"AAAAAAA"+ "','" +"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"+ "',  '" +0+ "')");
                w.execSQL("insert into Fin values( '" +"CCCCCCCCCCCC"+ "','" +"DDDDDDDDD"+ "',  '" +12+ "')");
                w.close();
                db.close();
                sleep(5000);
                Intent it = new Intent("pack1.exp.DASHBOARD");
                startActivity(it);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using sleep(5000)?

Comment: I wanted that splash image to occupy the screen for 5 secs

Answer (score 1):

Since the code remains the same, the only difference in the loading of the splash is the population of the table **Fin**. Check that this table is [optimized properly](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html), by checking indexes etc.  It might be that the query is getting slower to process with each load, especially if it has many indexes and a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

You should only sleep if the query takes less than 5 seconds. Other than that, I'm not sure why the query is taking more time each launch.

```
private CreateDatabase db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            db = new CreateDatabase(Splash.this);
            final SQLiteDatabase w = db.getWritableDatabase();
            w.execSQL("insert into Fin values( '" +"AAAAAAA"+ "','" +"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"+ "',  '" +0+ "')");
            w.execSQL("insert into Fin values( '" +"CCCCCCCCCCCC"+ "','" +"DDDDDDDDD"+ "',  '" +12+ "')");
            w.close();
            db.close();
            if((System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart) < 5000){
            sleep(5000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart)); //Only sleep if the database query takes less than 5 seconds
            }
            Intent it = new Intent("pack1.exp.DASHBOARD");
            startActivity(it);
            finish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be usefull, show a progress dialog whit the text you want and a spinning weel.

```
    private void startProgressDialogTimer() {
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
        context, "",
        context.getString(R.string.my_text_to_show));
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }
}, 5000);// show progressDialog for 5 secound
        }


       private CreateDatabase db;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    try {
        db = new CreateDatabase(Splash.this);
        final SQLiteDatabase w = db.getWritableDatabase();
        w.execSQL("insert into Fin values( '" +"AAAAAAA"+ "','"   +"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"+ "',  '" +0+ "')");
        w.execSQL("insert into Fin values( '" +"CCCCCCCCCCCC"+ "','" +"DDDDDDDDD"+ "',  '" +12+ "')");
        w.close();
        db.close();
        //sleep(5000); -- remove this
        startProgressDialogTimer //-- add this
        Intent it = new Intent("pack1.exp.DASHBOARD");
        startActivity(it);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: I really dont see why you should use thread...maybe you can tell me so we can figure this out..Cheers